# How can i send a email notification to a person who triggered the pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

**Usecase**

I am having a cross-account codepipeline where my codecommit in one account and my pipeline is in another account. My codecommit is source for the pipeline means any commit in that will trigger the pipeline. Codecommit is shared among 50 developers.

**Codepipeline Features**

I know the codepipeline will trigger emails based on cloudwatch events rules when there is a change in pipeline. For triggering emails we need to create SNS topic and add the subscribers to it. But the problem is the mail will trigger to all the guys who are in that topic.

**What i want**

I want to send an email to the owner and also to the person who triggered the codepipeline(i.e.Developer). Sending the email to the owner process can be done since the owner is one entity. But sending a mail to the person who triggered might be a tricky one. Is there any feature that AWS has for this type of usecase ?

**What i did and planning to do**

For now, i can able to the get the developer email id by using codecommit API method `getcommit` which will take `commitID` as input. So, that means i need to pass the `commitID` manually to get the email id of the developer. So, in the codepipeline i need to create a lambda function which create a SNS topic and add  developer emailID to it and create a cloudevent event rule with this SNS topic and delete as soon as the codepipeline gets complete.

Is there any better approach ?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I think you can create a distribution list and add the required email ids to that DL and then use that.

Comment: You are right @IllegalSkillsException .I want to send an email to the person who triggered it rather than sending to all the persons who are in DL.